API endpoint to retrieve version of a WordPress site?
Simple question:
Is there an API endpoint to retrieve the version of a specific WordPress site?
I need to monitor different WordPress sites and want to retrieve the version of these sites to be collected and checked for WordPress updates.
Is there a simple solution, something like example.com/api/version ?

For security reasons version is not added by default in https://yourdomain.com/wp-json
but you can add it. You can fetch the version after using curl or something. Also you can create your own api for that. Another way is to call  https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php

calling /wp-admin/upgrade.php tells me for every site that I'm up-to-date, even if I know there is a WordPress update...

I found a solution:
checking the content of the /wp-admin/upgrade.php file. It contains link tags with specific ?ver=x.x.x suffix that correspinds to the wordpress version.

WordPress does not provide built-in Api endpoint like example.com/api/version to directly retrieve the version of site. But you can try these method:

Check the readme.html file most wordpress have readme.html file in the root directory tha shows the version of wordpress. You can access by example.com/readme.html this file page contain version of wordpress

Use the wp-json REST API: You can use the WordPress REST API to get general site information. While it does not directly return the version number, you can find it with: example.com/wp-json/ Some security plugins may block this API or limit its information.


